# Conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010 do not have to be boolean?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I do not understand what 'conditional' means for conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio. Maybe somebody can explain the following behavior?

When setting a conditional breakpoint (selecting 'Is true' in the popup) I expect it to behave in the same way as an expression within an "if" statement.

For example:

```
    int x = 1;
    // (1) Breakpoint with expression "x == 1" returns True and the debugger stops here
    // (2) Breakpoint with expression "x != 1" returns False and the debugger does not stop here
    // (3) Breakpoint with expression "x = 42" returns ?? and the debugger stops here (!!) and executes the assignment(!!)
```

Case (3) is obviously a typo. If I place expression (3) in an "if" statement

```
    if (x = 42) { /* ... */ }
```

the code would not compile.

The typo in (3) can be dangerous. I've placed a [simple demo at GitHub](https://github.com/draptik/vs_debugger_conditional_demo) demonstrating the issue.

When reading the [MSDN docs on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340500.aspx) this should not happen, right?

Thankful for any pointers.

Update: [The code from GitHub](https://github.com/draptik/vs_debugger_conditional_demo/blob/master/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Simple program showing that Visual Studio's conditional breakpoints do not have to return boolean results.
        /// 
        /// Tested with:
        /// - Visual Studio 2005
        /// - Visual Studio 2010
        /// </summary>
        public class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var userService = new UserService();

                var userJon = new User {Id = 1, Name = "Jon Doe"};
                userService.SaveOrUpdateUser(userJon);

                var userSally = new User { Id = 2, Name = "Sally Sample" };
                userService.SaveOrUpdateUser(userSally);

                foreach (var user in userService.Users) {

                    // IMPORTANT: Add a conditional breakpoint on the next line with 'user.id = 1' (instead of 'user.id == 1' or 'user.id.Equals(1)'). See doc folder for screenshots.
                    int id = user.Id;

                    // ...some logic...

                    user.Id = id;

                    // ...some more logic...

                    userService.SaveOrUpdateUser(user);
                }

                // Show results of what just happened on command line
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nRESULTS==================================");
                foreach (var user in userService.Users) {
                    Console.WriteLine("User Id: " + user.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("User Name: " + user.Name);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nEND RESULTS==================================");

                // Add a 'normal' breakpoint on the next line to read the console output
            }

        }

        internal class UserService
        {
            public UserService()
            {
                Users = new List<User>();
            }

            public List<User> Users { get; private set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Imagine this method doing a database insert or update!
            /// </summary>
            public void SaveOrUpdateUser(User user)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tSaveOrUpdateUser...");
                Console.WriteLine("\tUser Id: " + user.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("\tUser Name: " + user.Name);

                User userAlreadyPresent = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name.Equals(user.Name)); // dummy find method

                if (userAlreadyPresent == null) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Adding new user");

                    Users.Add(user);    
                }
                else {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUPDATING USER.......................");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tOld infos about user:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUser id: " + userAlreadyPresent.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUser name: " + userAlreadyPresent.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tNew infos about user:");
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUser id: " + user.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUser name: " + user.Name);

                    userAlreadyPresent.Id = user.Id;
                }
            }
        }

        internal class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying that if you place `x = 42` into the conditional field for the breakpoint, it _assigns_ a value of 42 to the `x` variable currently executing in the code _and_ breaks at the same time?  Such that, when you continue executing from that breakpoint, `x` in your code will now have the value 42?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Yes, that is the case. Please try the very [simple example I posted to GitHub](https://github.com/draptik/vs_debugger_conditional_demo)

Comment: The debugger is not a compiler.

Comment: @Hans Passant ;-) might be true?

Comment: @Chris Sinclair - That's exactly what C/C++ does, & what I'd expect it to do, i.e. that is what it has been told to do. I'm surprised it wouldn't compile, a warning would suffice IMHO. After all you can say `if (CallFunction())` in C# and expect the function to be called inside the `if`. To not execute the code is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debugger works for debugging programs.  Those programs may be written in any number of languages. F#, C#, VB, Assembly, C++, C, etc.  Each of those languages has different semantics for it's ability to evaluate an expression true or not.  The debugger really doesn't do anything very specific for a specific language (and in fact, probably doesn't even know a particular bit of code it gets a breakpoint on was written in any particular language).  It really just knows where things are in memory, and what they represent.

Long story short, it doesn't abide by the C# syntax when evaluating expressions for conditional breakpoints.